# pscp Server refused our key

Tags: ssh, putty, google-cloud

Есть виртуальная машина в гугл облаке на Ubuntu

При помощи `puttygen.exe` я сгенерироваал пару ключей. Публичный ключ залил в консоль управления гугла.

В putty создал и настроил сессию с именем `test` для подключения к машине. Ввожу

```
putty -load test
```

у меня запрашивается пароль к приватному ключу и после этого устанавливается соединение. Никаких логинов и паролей больше не запрашивается.

Теперь я хочу на удаленную машину передать файл. Запускаю

```
pscp.exe -load test readme.txt "user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:readme.txt"
```

Никаких запросов паролей не выполняется. Вместо этого получаю ответ

> Server refused our key
>   Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Что я делаю не так? Почему ключ подходит при подключении через `putty` и не принимается при подключении через `pscp.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Только написал вопрос - и сразу нашел ответ.

Из `pscp.exe` я подключался по другому IP адресу. Соответственно левый сервер очень удивлялся видя мои ключи

Причем при первом подключении `pscp.exe` у меня спросил на счет неизвестного fingerprint, тогда как `putty` уже запрашивал у меня о fingerprint с моего сервера